# Take input value and show div

Tags: javascript, jquery

How I can show a `div` defined by an input's value?

For example if I type `dress` in the input field `#showme` will show.

```
<form>
  <input type="text" id="desc" value="" onKeyUp="myFunction()"/>
  <div id="showme">
    <input type="text" value="" />
    <input type="text" value="" />
  </div>
```

I tried this, but it's unfortunately not working

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction()
    {
        var input = document.getElementById('desc')
        var div = document.getElementById('showme');
        div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + input.value;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why would that code show or hide anything, it doesn't seem to do anything like that? Do you really mean you want to *show* an element, as in change it to be from invisible to visible? Or do you mean you want what was typed into the `#desc` input to show up at the end of `#showme`? You need to be more clear, and you should really know by now *"not working"* isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like

```js
function myFunction(el) {
  var div = document.getElementById('showme');
  var descval = document.getElementById('descval');
  descval.innerHTML = el.value;
  div.style.display = el.value == 'dress' ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

```css
#showme {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="desc" value="" onKeyUp="myFunction(this)" />
  <div id="showme">
    <input type="text" value="" />
    <input type="text" value="" />
    <!-- a span is used here so that there wouldn't be multiple appends -->
    <span id="descval"></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: thank's for your answer but is there any way value works also in 2 words for example `dress white`

Comment: @jhunlio how is it... is it that it can be either `dress` or `white`? or is it a single word?

Comment: @jhunlio try changing `el.value == 'dress'` to `el.value == 'dress' || el.value == 'white'`

Comment: sorry my bad, actually your answer is working but in my problem I use jquery.autocomplete here the links http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ to get data from data base and work like google search so i can select it from the suggestion. but any way thank you for the support

Answer (score 1):

On you `myFunction` method, after selecting the `showme` div you can make it visible by setting visibility to visible:

```
    div.style.visibility = "visible";
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bardhlohaj/mmy5sv4u/2/)